# Solving simultaneous linear equations in positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given nonnegative integers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_n$, I would like to find 
nonnegative integers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ so that the following equations hold:

$$ a_1 + b_1 x_1 = a_2 + b_2 x_2 = a_3 + b_3 x_3 = \cdots = a_n + b_n x_n$$

If all $a_i$ are zero, then a solution is $x_i = {\rm lcm}(b_1, \ldots, b_n)/b_i$. I don't know how to solve this if some of the $a_i$s are not zero.

Comment: It's certainly not always possible to find such $x_i$'s; for example, let $a_1=0$, $a_1=1$, and $b_1=b_2=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to solve the system of congruences, $X\equiv a_i\pmod{b_i}$, $i=1,\dots,n$. The Chinese Remainder Theorem, q.v., tells you when this is possible, and you will also find expositions of how to do it when it is possible.